# Use a regex to keep the access logs with HTTP response 4** and 5**

Tags: graylog, graylog3

I'm using Graylog to manage my server logs.

I would like to filter the apache logs access to keep the logs with a http response code 4** and 5**

So I would like to use a regex:

If I search `/HTTP/` I have the corresponding logs like:

```
[...] "HEAD /register HTTP/1.1" 301 460 "-" [...]
```

But if I search `/HTTP\//`, I have no message. I also tried with `/HTTP\\//` but same result.

I tried with the regex `/HTTP(?:.*?)"\s[4|5](?:\d{2})/` but no message found.

How to search a simple pattern like `HTTP/` with a regex in Graylog ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use an extractor to map http-status-codes to fields.

Then you can easily filter and group your logs to find those with special codes.

Please see the following links

[Extractors](https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.2/pages/extractors.html)

[How to use a JSON extractor](https://www.graylog.org/videos/json-extractor)